# Django class field in if statement

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I currently have two different types of user 'Lecturer' and 'Student'. In the html I am trying to create an if statement that only applies if the user is equal to one or the other. I have created this in the models.py class (everything else works)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Student', 'Student'),
        ('Lecturer', 'Lecturer'),
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
    ) 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_user = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='s',choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

The problem is the if statement in the HTML does not seem to be printing anything

```
{% if user.userprofile.type_user == 'Lecturer' %}
<p>Lecturer</p>
{% elif user.userprofile.type_user == 'Student' %}
<p>Student</p>
{% endif %}
```

Please go easy, I am new to Django

Comment: Did you make sure the user profile you are loading has its type_user saved as 'Lecturer' or 'Student', and not the default 's'? And what does your view code look like?

Comment: Do the following in your template to debug what is really in that property: `{{ user.userprofile.type_user }}`. If it is empty, then you need to check if you are really passing `user` into the template's context.

Comment: @Whodini I am ever so sorry, I was logged into an admin account and that's why it wasn't working. My apologies for wasting your time, I appreciate the effort though!

Comment: @malberts I am ever so sorry, I was logged into an admin account and that's why it wasn't working. My apologies for wasting your time, I appreciate the effort though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it, I was logged into an admin account and that's why it wasn't working.